# Tap and go feature not working on Android lollipop

Tags: android-5.0-lollipop

I follow [Transfer your Google Account information to a new device](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6073630?hl=en-GB) to transfer my current device content to new device but I am getting "couldn't restore from backup" message on my new device when setup process completes.
On my current device it shows notification "New device set-up completed" but nothing happens on my new device.

I am using 2 Nexus 7 with Android 5.0.1

Has anyone tried it successfully?

Comment: I'm having the same problem migrating from a Nexus 5 to a Nexus 6. Tried it a dozen times, resetting to factory defaults and all and get nothing but that message and nothing gets restored. Any clue?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to http://android.stackexchange.com/